# Loading Skeleton implementation in NextJS / React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm fetching a set of video links from an Amazon S3 bucket, and mapping them into a video player component called HoverVideoPlayer:

```
 {data?.slice(0, 10).map((item: any) => (
      <div key={item.id}>
        {data ? (
          <HoverVideoPlayer videoSrc={item.videoLink} />
        ) : (
          <Skeleton count={10} />
        )}
      </div>
    ))}
```

This leads to a loading experience in which multiple images /videos are  scaling up inside a Tailwind grid component until they are fully loaded, distorting the layout:

[image]

In order to improve this loading into something more refined as used at YouTube , I have implemented 'React Loading Skeleton' in an effort to have a fixed sized preloader that takes up the space of the grid column, until the video is fully loaded and scaled preventing layout jumps.

[image]

This is my 10th+ attempt to implement the Loading Skeleton and getting it to display during the loading / scale up time. I have adjusted the height and width of the Skeleton, put the  component over and under the player, adjusted the import to the precise data fetch location:

```
            <HoverVideoPlayer
                  videoSrc={item.videoLink || <Skeleton count={10} />}
                />
```

but no success, not even the slightest appearance of a Loading Skeleton. What am I doing wrong?

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/happy-antonelli-dt1enq?file=%2Fpages%2Findex.tsx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand you want the skeleton to show while the data is fetching ?

I think something like this should work :

```
<main className={styles.main}>
   {!data?.length && new Array(10).fill().map(() => <Skeleton count={10} />)}}
   {data?.slice(0, 10).map((item: any) => (
      <div key={item.id}>
         <HoverVideoPlayer videoSrc={item.videoLink}  />
      </div>
    ))}
</main>
```

And don't forget to import the styles for skeleton :

`import 'react-loading-skeleton/dist/skeleton.css'`

Comment: This helped me tremendously! I now got at least the Skeleton visible! Thank you so much!

Could you elaborate this portion:
{!data?.length && <Skeleton count={10} />}

For me please?

Comment: It says that if you have no data (empty array, undefined or null), it will show the Skeleton.

Comment: You could use the useMemo hook to avoid re-rendering the HoverVideoPlayer component unnecessarily, it's a good practice.

Comment: @OneQ:

I have 10 HoverVideoPlayer components mapped in the CodeSandBox, 

In my real application it's 30+, but only one React Skeleton is displayed for all of the video. Any idea how I can give every of the mapped elements a Loading Skeleton?

Comment: You set the count to 10 so you have 10 Skeleton, but as you see in the doc one Skeleton is just one line but you can style it

Comment: @OneQ: sadly the count={10} is for the number of lines used that are displayed during the preloading ,not the total number of Skeletons.

<Skeleton count={5} /> = ONE  loading skeleton with 5 Lines
<Skeleton count={10} /> = ONE loading skeleton with 10 Lines

Comment: @DennoFreezy I updated the code, I hope it's what you need